# For the fit method in LinearRegression in scikit-learn, why is the second parameter consisting of y coordinates required?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

The objects of LinearRegression from sklearn.linear_model can be used to fit data point to a line. As can be seen from the code below, the fit method takes two parameters, the list of points and another list of just y coordinates.

```
from sklearn import linear_model
reg = linear_model.LinearRegression()
reg.fit ([[0, 0], [1, 1], [2, 2]], [0, 1, 2])
```

My question is this: why is the second parameter even required? Is it not redundant information?

Comment: No it's not redundant. It's a basic requirement and follows the API which is build for supervised-classification/regression. [Tutorial](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html#ordinary-least-squares) including formula. If you are confused by the plot (which is build on lower-dim linreg), read [this](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/linear_model/plot_ols.html): ```This example uses only the first feature of the diabetes dataset```

Answer (score 3):

Linear models are not restricted to only 1 predictor variable and 1 response variable. In other words, you can have X and Y as the two predictors being used to predict the response variable Z, where Z might depend linearly on X and Y. In your case you are only trying to predict Y from X, so change your code to the following:

```
from sklearn import linear_model
reg = linear_model.LinearRegression()
reg.fit ([[0], [1], [2]], [0, 1, 2])
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, this syntax supports fitting for a problem of of type `y = a.x_1 + b.x_2 + c`. Then, the first parameter is a list of n-dimensional vectors.

Also, like you said in the last line, it doesn't make sense for me to use 2d vectors as input then. In fact, it should give the wrong answer.

Comment: Yes, it supports that type of problem. And yes, the first parameter is a list of n-dimensional vectors, where n is the number of predictors you are using to predict the response variable.

Comment: That is correct, using 2d vectors as input would in fact give you the wrong answer because the size of the resulting coefficient matrix would be different.

Comment: This makes a lot more sense now. I ran this version of the code and found that `reg.fit ([[0], [1], [2]], [0, 1, 2])` fits to the line y = x as expected and `reg.coef_` returns 1. In case of `reg.fit ([[0, 0], [1, 1], [2, 2]], [0, 1, 2])`, `reg.coef_` returned `[ 0.4,  0.8]`. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 2):

> to fit data point to a line

It rather fits a line through your data points.

> fit method takes two parameters, the list of points and another list of just y coordinates.

`X` are your data samples, where each row is a datapoint (one sample, a N-dimensional feature vector).
`y` are the datapoint labels, one per datapoint. `fit` method finds matrix `W` (feature weights) and vector `b` (bias), such that it minimizes distance between your prediction `yhat = Wx + b` and the real `y`.

E.g. if you are given 2-dimensional datapoints with coordinates `[x,y]` and you would like to predict `y` based on `x`, you pass `x`s as the first argument and `y`s as the second argument to `fit`.